# Problems with ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> .. JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

It is an arraylist of arraylists of integers. I'm still running into an issue though when I try to compile. The command prompt says "incompatible types."
I know for sure that all the function calls are correct (i.e.: .getStart(), .getEnd(), etc. - I wrote those classes and have tested them thoroughly.)
Btw, "permOfEdges" is: ArrayList <ArrayList<Edge>> (Edge being a class I wrote.)

Since it's:
visited.get(-).get(-), it says the second .get(-) should be a variable not a value. I'm confused on what it means since it's an arraylist of arraylists.

Code for arraylist of arraylists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> visited = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int i = 1; i < permOfEdges.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < permOfEdges.get(i).size(); j++)
        {
            visited.get(i).get(j) = 0;  // this is to initialize the entire thing to only contain zeros
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < permOfEdges.size(); i++)
    {
        for(Edge point: permOfEdges.get(i))
        {   
            if((visited.get(point.getEnd()).get(point.getStart()) == 0) && visited.get(point.getStart().get(point.getEnd()) == 0))  // means NOT visited yet
            {
                writer.println(point.getStart() + " " + point.getEnd() + " " + point.getDistance() + " " + point.getPrice());
            }
            visited.get(point.getStart()).get(point.getEnd()) = 1;
            visited.get(point.getEnd()).get(point.getStart()) = 1;
        }
    }

    writer.close();
```

The error reads:
1. unexpected types:
                     visited.get(i).get*(j) = 0     (* = where the ^ was in the command prompt)
required: variable
found: value

2. int cannot be dereferenced 
          if((visited.get(point.getEnd()).get*(point.getStart()) == 0) &&...)
3. and 4.
   both of these errors are the same as the first one except it focuses on the two lines where I assign visited.get(..).get(..) = 1

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: **permOfEdges is ArrayList<ArrayList<Edge>> 

(Edge being a class I wrote)

Comment: don't comment your own question, rather update it.

Comment: I don't see where you create the inner List?

Comment: Which inner list?
And sorry, I'm very new to stack overflow

Comment: The only error I have right now is that it doesn't like the if statement. It says that it is "int cannot be dereferenced" do you know what that means?
@jangroth

Comment: I would recommend learning about Lists / ArrayLists in a separate, easier example. There are quite a few misconceptions from your end, and the piece of code seems way too complex to deal with them all at once (as the amount of comments so far indicates).

Comment: Thanks. I just think my big issue is that some of my arrays begin at 0 and others begin at 1. So I just need to map it out. Thank you for your help. @jangroth

Comment: I think, at the very least, you are confusing arrays with ArrayList. And Maps with Lists. And scopes of variables (you are using `int i` within `int i`). And you normally don't initialise ArrayList with any size. And you would always use interfaces over implementations. And I'm not sure if you are aware of autoboxing taking place. And the whole example could be written much more clearly / readable / maintainable. Hence my recommendation to start a bit easier.... ;)

Comment: you are not confusing scopes. my bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to the result of a method call. This is wrong:

```
visited.get(i).get(j) = 1;
```

and you presumably meant:

```
visited.get(i).set(j, 1);
```

Comment: Also, do you have any idea about why the if statement would be throwing an error?

Comment: @Nupur whoops, it's called `set`. (`put` is for maps)

Comment: Thank you! I realized, it shouldn't be .put(), it should be .set(). So I just have one error now and it is due to the if statement.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about why it would say that I am "dereferencing" the int??

Comment: @Nupur Because you are trying to call a method on an int, in another place. Also, one question per question...

Comment: I don't understand. Where else am I calling a method on an int?

Comment: I see that the problem with the if statement is because I don't initialize the size of the arraylist for visited. Do you know how to initialize this?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I have finished initializing it. There is a problem with my indexes. I have to make the outter arraylist begin at 1 but the inners begin at 0. but the getStart() and getEnd() return 1 - 9. That's why it throws everything off.